# Fetching image in ImageView dynamically from a fragment always returns 0 as resourceid

Tags: android, android-listview

Before asking this question, I have already gone through all links and still not able to solve the problem.

I have a Fragment containing a customized list View and I am trying to fetch a image in imageView(for each list item) dynamically from a string.(String is generated from database, and name of the String matches the imagenames in drawable.* folders)

In every possible way, I just get the the emageResouce int value as 0.
I have checked completely,The images name(in drawable folders) matches with the generated string.

following is the code:--

```
int imageResource = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("android.banking:drawable/" + bank.getImageName(), null, null);
Log.d("BankListFragment", getContext().getPackageName() +"  "+imageResource +" "+bank.getImageName());
image.setImageResource(imageResource);


int imgResource = res.getIdentifier(bank.getImageName(), "drawable", getContext().getPackageName() );
Log.d("BankListFragment", getContext().getPackageName() +"  "+imgResource  +" "+bank.getImageName());
```

If I try to hardcode the image name in layout file with src="@drawable/image1", its works.
Also if I use the following code, it works--

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.image1);
image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Anyone faced similar issue?

EDIT::- Here goes the logcat output:--correct image names are printed and drawable folder has all these files.

```
09-01 15:47:34.051  17620-17620/android.banking D/BankListFragment﹕ android.banking  0 image1.jpg
09-01 15:47:34.051  17620-17620/android.banking D/BankListFragment﹕ android.banking  0 image2.jpg
09-01 15:47:34.061  17620-17620/android.banking D/BankListFragment﹕ android.banking  0 image3.jpg
09-01 15:47:34.061  17620-17620/android.banking D/BankListFragment﹕ android.banking  0 image4.jpg
09-01 15:47:34.061  17620-17620/android.banking D/BankListFragment﹕ android.banking  0 image5.jpg
09-01 15:47:34.061  17620-17620/android.banking D/BankListFragment﹕ android.banking  0 image6.jpg
09-01 15:47:34.061  17620-17620/android.banking D/BankListFragment﹕ android.banking  0 image7.jpg
```

Comment: what does `bank.getImageName()` returned?

Comment: Can you post the logcat trace?

Comment: done the EDIT and added logcat output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the similar issue and what worked for me was the string without extension.

The string which you are generating, should not contain the extension.

The way you are accessing in Drawable code is without extension, I think you need to modify the logic of image name generation String.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
int resourceId = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier(bank.getImageName(),"drawable",getActivity().getPackageName());
```